Why can't I center my button in media queries
So I made two buttons in a grid, and in order for them to sit closer to each other I use justify-self: start and justify-self: end to the buttons. Everything works just fine until I made a media queries. These two buttons won't center themselves even though I have set them to center.


@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap");

:root {
  --color-1: #ff8787;
  --color-2: #475569;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: var(--color-2);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--color-2);
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Navbar */
.navbar {
  background-color: var(--color-1);
  height: 70px;
}

.navbar .flex {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-middle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav-middle a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.login {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.menu-sub {
  position: absolute;
  width: fit-content;
  display: none;

  background: #ddd;
  color: var(--color-2);

  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-middle li:hover .menu-sub,
.nav-middle li:active .menu-sub {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}

.menu-sub a {
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.35em;
}

.menu-sub a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.menu-category {
  margin: 2.5rem 0 0.5em;
}

.menu-category:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.menu-col-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.menu-sub-left {
  background-color: #7950f2;

  padding: 1rem 1rem;
}

.menu-sub ul {
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
}

/* Showcase */
.showcase {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: var(--color-1);
  columns: var(--color-2);
  position: relative;
}

.showcase h1 {
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.showcase p {
  margin: 1.5rem 0;
}

.showcase .grid div {
  display: grid;
}

.showcase .grid div:first-of-type a {
  justify-self: end;
}

.showcase .grid div:nth-of-type(2) a {
  justify-self: start;
}

/* Utilities */
/* Text sizes */
.lead {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sm {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.mdm {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.lg {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.xl {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

/* margin */
.my-1 {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.my-2 {
  margin: 1.5rem 0;
}

.my-3 {
  margin: 2rem 0;
}

.my-4 {
  margin: 3rem 0;
}

.my-5 {
  margin: 4rem 0;
}

.m-1 {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.m-2 {
  margin: 1.5rem;
}

.m-3 {
  margin: 2rem;
}

.m-4 {
  margin: 3rem;
}

.m-5 {
  margin: 4rem;
}

/* padding */
.py-1 {
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.py-2 {
  padding: 1.5rem 0;
}

.py-3 {
  padding: 2rem 0;
}

.py-4 {
  padding: 3rem 0;
}

.py-5 {
  padding: 4rem 0;
}

.p-1 {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.p-2 {
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.p-3 {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.p-4 {
  padding: 3rem;
}

.p-5 {
  padding: 4rem;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #845ef7;
  color: var(--color-2);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #7950f2;
}

.btn-outline {
  background-color: #ff8787;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-2);
}

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.123);
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid-3 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

/* Media queries */
/* Tablets and Under */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .showcase {
    height: auto;
  }

  .grid,
  .showcase .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  }

  .showcase .grid a {
    justify-self: center;
  }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <script
      type="module"
      src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      nomodule
      src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"
    ></script>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-SnH5WK+bZxgPHs44uWIX+LLJAJ9/2PkPKZ5QiAj6Ta86w+fsb2TkcmfRyVX3pBnMFcV7oQPJkl9QevSCWr3W6A=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="utilities.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Just Project 1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="container flex">
        <h1 class="logo">AcademyOfCode</h1>
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav-middle">
            <li>
              <a href="#"
                >Catalog <ion-icon name="caret-down-outline"></ion-icon
              ></a>
              <div class="menu-sub">
                <div class="menu-col-1">
                  <div class="menu-sub-left">
                    <h3 class="menu-category">Course recommendations</h3>
                    <p>Explore our paid or free courses</p>
                  </div>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Python</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">JavaScript</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Html</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">CSS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">SQL</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="">C++</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Java</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">PHP</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">C#</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">R</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"
                >Pricing <ion-icon name="caret-down-outline"></ion-icon
              ></a>
              <div class="menu-sub">
                <div>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="">For students</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">For individuals</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">For teams</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"
                >Community <ion-icon name="caret-down-outline"></ion-icon
              ></a>
              <div class="menu-sub">
                <div>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Discord</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Instagram</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">YouTube</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Github</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav-right">
            <li>
              <a class="btn btn-outline" href="#">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Showcase -->
    <section class="showcase">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="showcase-text text-center">
          <h1 class="xl">AcademyOfCode empowers you to build tech fluency</h1>
          <p class="mdm">Build your tech skill here with CodeOfAcademy</p>
          <div class="grid">
            <div>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Get Started</a>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline">Learn to Code</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>



I want these two buttons be on the center in media queries. I have tried using justify-self: center, but it didn't work.
